# Ceramic Capacitor 10uF NP0 Cold Temperatures

Tags: capacitor, pcb-design, decoupling-capacitor, bypass-capacitor

For my pcb which will be used at very low temperatures, say 50 K, I am searching appropriate Bypass Caps. Many papers stated that NP0(C0G) Caps are especially good because of their constant temperature behaviour. 
But now the problem is that I need a 10 uF Bypass, which does not exist with NP0 dielectricum.. What alternatives do I have?

Till now I have a 1 nF (size 0603), 10 nF (0603), 100 nF (1203) all NP0 Ceramics.

Appreciate any help

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like solid tantalum can be suitable for larger values at cryogenic temperatures, on the following nasa study the "in situ" column is when the part is still at liquid nitrogen temperatures.

[image]

[Nasa Study](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19980137723.pdf)

Comment: Sorry but looking at the table it looks like Solid Tantalum are the worst of all ?!

Comment: Based on the other component sizes you gave, and would appear your using it for bulk decoupling, it will be the most compact, 10uF film caps are not small,